# How To Disable Google Sheets Cells Coordinates Reading with ChromeVox Screen Reader feature?

Tags: google-sheets, google-chrome-extension, accessibility, screen-readers

I'm wondering if there's a known way to disable the reading of Google Sheets' Cells Coordinates with [ChromeVox Screen reader](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-reader/kgejglhpjiefppelpmljglcjbhoiplfn) accessibility Extension?

Currently the reader reads the cells content but also utters each cell's coordinates at the end of each uttereances.

Also, when moving up or down on an empty cell it utters it's coordinates.

Is there a way to disable those previous cases utterances while only keeping ChromeVox to read the cells content of non-empty cells in Gooogle Sheets?

I haven't found any documentation on the accessibilty page and thus couldn't try anything so far.

Any known help or suggestion is greatly appreciated.

The documentation I could gather:

[Edit spreadsheets with a screen reader](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1632199)

[Use the built-in screen reader](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/7031755?hl=en#zippy=%2Cuse-the-chromevox-menu)

[Getting started with Google Sheets using a screen reader](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oCYT63b_m88)

[https://google.com/accessible](https://about.google/belonging/disability-inclusion/)

Comment: That would be a chromevox feature.  Both NVDA and JAWS, screen readers that users actually use, have a feature to turn off table coordinates. Chromevox is not a standard screen reader that you should rely on to do accessibility testing. As noted in [this survey](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/#primary), Chromevox is used about 0.3% of the time compared to JAWS 53.7% and NVDA 30.7%.

Comment: Many thanks for that very helpful comment. I'll have a look at JAWS next.

Comment: Hello again, NVDA doesn't play the sound when navigating on Google Sheets cells (Chrome Browser). Any solution you know you'd share? I installed NVDA, enabled `Turn on screen reader support` in Google Sheets, and followed this setting adjustment `Press NVDA + Ctrl + k, then turn off Speak typed characters and Speak typed words.` (from the Keyboard menu), from this link https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6282736#zippy=%2Cnvda  instructions, but no sound. It only says `Chrome Legacy Window` when I move the mouse on the Google Sheets Sheet.

Comment: Found this new doc: https://webaim.org/articles/nvda/ I tried enabling highlights and restarting Chrome and now it reads Cells content all right. Now I need to find how  ot disable the Cells coordinates reading. I'll be back asa I find it.

Comment: @slugolicious Could you please share the shortcut or documentation for disabling the coordinates rading with NVDA? I looked at those sources but can't find it: https://dequeuniversity.com/assets/pdf/screenreaders/nvda.pdf  https://www.nvaccess.org/files/nvdaTracAttachments/455/keycommands%20with%20laptop%20keyboard%20layout.html https://webaim.org/articles/nvda/#tables

Comment: Bring up NVDA settings (Ins+N to display the NVDA menu then select "Preferences" then "Settings"). Navigate to "Document Formatting" in the "Categories" list then navigate to the "Table Information" grouping and uncheck the "Cell coordinates" checkbox.

Comment: Great it works! You rock, many thanks! Couldn't have guessed it was there in "Document Formating". Very helpful! Be well!

Comment: I'll move my comments to the answer section so you can approve it so others can benefit from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*(Moving my comments to an answer. The OP asked later in the comments how to turn the feature off in NVDA so that is also answered here.)*

Turning off table cell coordinates would be a screen reader feature so chromevox would need an option to turn it off. Both NVDA and JAWS, screen readers that users actually use, have a feature to turn off table coordinates. Chromevox is not a standard screen reader that you should rely on to do accessibility testing. As noted in [this survey](https://webaim.org/projects/screenreadersurvey9/#primary), Chromevox is used about 0.3% of the time compared to JAWS 53.7% and NVDA 30.7%.

[image]

For NVDA,

- Bring up Settings

  - <kbd>Ins</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd> to display the NVDA menu
  - then select "Preferences"
  - then "Settings"
- Navigate to "Document Formatting" in the "Categories" list
- Navigate to the "Table Information" grouping
- Uncheck the "Cell coordinates" checkbox

[image]

Comment: Great help! Thanks again, will surely help others better! Be well!